# Username unique when insert data in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

Am newbie to coldfusion please give me solution how to insert username unique in coldfusion?

Is there any default option in coldfusion like(Maxlength,required etc...) or else we checked query with that form data username once count greater than zero means return false to submit data Is it correct?

Comment: there is no way from client side. you have to use query to check for unique username

Comment: The part of your question starting with `or else` is what you need to do.

Comment: how to show alert in coldfusion 8,once count greater than zero means?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax to invoke a function with the username as a parameter and check using the select query to see if the username exists.

```
<cffunction name="checkUsernameExists" access="public" returnType="numeric" >
    <cfargument required="yes" name="username" type="string" >
    <cfset local.userExistsFlag = 0 >
    <cfquery name="qCheckUsernameExists" datasource="datasource_name" >
        select username 
        from table_name
        where username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.username#" >
    </cfquery>
    <cfif qCheckUsernameExists.recordcount >
        <cfset local.userExistsFlag = 1 >
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn local.userExistsFlag >
</cffunction>
```

If the returned value is 1 then the username exists else username doesn't exist.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "user.cfc?method=checkUsernameExists",
       data: {"username":username},
       success: function(data) {
           //handle the response here
       }
  });
```